# C++: References to pointers mixed with vectors. I'm having trouble with it

Tags: java, c++, pointers, vector, reference

I'm a newbie in programming, but have studied some `C` and `Java`.

I'm now beginning to study `C++`. One of the first exercises I assigned for myself was to translate a small program written in `Java` to `C++`. Now, as I understand it, `Java` seems to use **pointers to objects** for everything behind the scenes (what is called in `Java` "reference variables") or **addresses to objects** (what is called in `Java` "reference"), hence why you can't directly manipulate objects like in `C++`, instead using the "reference" for it.

Because of that, I wanted to write this program the closest as possible to this *Java logic*, using pointers for any object instead of using objects themselves. However I ran into a problem while trying using **range-based loops** (for-each) with **vectors**. The only workaround I found was to use a **traditional loop** (regular for) or to just ditch this *Java logic* and use objects directly. I want however to use pointers, not the objects themselves.

Is it really impossible? If not, what do I have to change in my code?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

using namespace std;

class File;

class FileGenerator {
    public:
        void generateFile(vector<File *> * &files);
};
class File {
    public:
        virtual void generate() = 0;
};
class FilePDF : public File{
    public:
        void generate();
};
class FileXML : public File {
    public:
        void generate();
};

void FileXML::generate(){
    cout << "Generating XML file... " << endl;
}

void FilePDF::generate(){
    cout << "Generating PDF file... " << endl;
}
void FileGenerator::generateFile(vector<File *> * &files){
    ///THIS WORKS FINE!
//    for(int i = 0; i < files->size(); i++){
//        files->at(i)->generate();
//    }
    ///THIS DOES NOT WORK!
    for(File *file : *files){
        file->generate();
    }
}

int main(){
    vector<File *> *files = new vector<File *>;
    files->push_back(new FilePDF);
    files->push_back(new FileXML);

    FileGenerator *fileGenerator = new FileGenerator();
    fileGenerator->generateFile(files);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Cannot reproduce: https://ideone.com/mZjlzu

Comment: OP: _How_ does that not work? Is the result wrong? What result did you get? Did it not compile? What was the error?

Comment: Holy... My command prompt crashes when I run from CodeBlocks IDE. I have no clue what to do now. Reinstall CodeBlocks? Reinstall g++?

Comment: In fact, there is a warning for first method. Second method compiles fine.

Comment: Have you enabled C++11 in your compiler?

Comment: Oh, and btw. In C++, not every object has to be created with `new`. In fact, we try to avoid it as much as possible, along with using raw pointers. `std::vector` is perfectly fine for placing on the stack, because it allocates memory for data on the heap by itself. You can then easily pass it around by reference.

Comment: @Yksisarvinen Checked out the version of `g++` from command prompt: *g++ (tdm-1) 5.1.0
Copyright (C) 2015 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
This is free soft* **[...]** is this really the problem?

Comment: According to documentation, gcc in version 5.1.0 still had C++03 as default standard version. In Code::Blocks, somewhere in compiler options, you should find an option to enable C++11 (or add `-std=c++11` flag manually to compiler)

Comment: @Yksisarvinen Thanks very much. I don't know if I should delete this question now. Lol I feel so stupid now.